# Sequelize + Azure Mysql

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, azure-mysql-database

I`m Trying to connect to Azure Mysql using

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.environment.db.db_one.name,
    config.environment.db.db_one.user,
    config.environment.db.db_one.pass, {
      host: config.environment.db.db_one.host,
      port: config.environment.db.db_one.port,
      dialect: 'mysql',
      define: {
        freezeTableName: true
      },
      ssl: true,
      dialectOptions: {
        ssl:{
          ca: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('db', "DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem"))
        }
      }
    });
```

On the server, there are a DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem file under "db" folder.

On **localhost**, my application works fine, but on **Azure** the app continuously crash and returns this error when I run `node index.js` with KUDU bash

```
ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at ConnectionManager.connect (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:102:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async ConnectionManager._connect (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:220:24)
    at async /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:174:32
    at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:197:7)
    at async /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:305:26
    at async Sequelize.authenticate (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:457:5) {
  parent: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
      at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:205:17)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {
    errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    syscall: 'connect',
    fatal: true
  },
  original: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
      at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:205:17)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {
    errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    syscall: 'connect',
    fatal: true
  }
}
❌ Error connecting to database!
```

Other screenshot from "Availability and Performance" section

[image]

What's wrong?